# How to run client-server socket program using different 'C' projects in eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, sockets

I want to run server-client program in eclipse. I made two different projects one for client and other one to server. while running the project for client
i am getting error as "connect no such file or directory in eclipse".
I tried the same by putting one project in different workspace still getting the same error..
i would like to know what changes i should make to fix this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is to do with you #include file not being found. Either you have not included the appropriate library for the code you're trying to execute, or the library does not exist in the directory. Regardless, for this issue to be resolved you need to provide a sample of your code